# show only company that have a job rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a association between jobs and companies where jobs belongs_to:company and company have_many jobs. In a view page I want to show only the companies that have a job how to achieve this

Comment: Please add more details, this is not an answerable question in it's current form.

Comment: What have you tried? Where errors do you get or where are you stuck? Can you provide a simple code example?

Comment: it is like to show only posts that are commented

Comment: i have tried this code  <% unless job.company_name.empty? %>
<% jobs.coompanies.each do |company| %> <%= @company.name %> 
                      <% end %> <% end %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have well done your association between the two models, you can get

- The company's jobs by doing: `company.jobs`
- A job's company with the code: `job.company`

So, if you want to display the name of the companies which provide at least one job, you can do:

```
<% Company.all.each do |company| %>
   <%= company.name unless company.jobs.empty? %>
<% end %>
```

#### Edit

If you want to limit the number of outputs to 5, you can do it with a custom SQL request, using some ActiveRecord methods.

For example, this code can do the trick:

```
Company.joins('INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.company_id = companies.id')
       .group('companies.id')
       .having('COUNT(jobs.id) > 0')
       .limit(5)
```

This will do a SQL join between the two tables, selecting only the companies with at least one job. Then, it will limit the number of results to 5.

A good application of this code would be to use ActiveRecord scopes, wich will make your code more readable.

For example, in your `app/model/Company.rb` file, you can create a `with_jobs` scope and a `only_five` scope:

```
 scope :with_jobs, -> { joins('INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.company_id = companies.id').group('companies.id').having('COUNT(jobs.id) > 0') }

 scope :only_five, -> { limit(5) }
```

Then, in your view, you can simply do:

```
<% Company.with_jobs.only_five.each do |company| %>
   <%= company.name %>
<% end %>
```

I advise you to read the [ActiveRecord Official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). It's a really useful guide.